# javascript child window redirecting main window

Tags: javascript, window, self, window.opener

main.php has

```
<a href="redirect.php" target="_blank">open new window</a>
```

then redirect.php has

```
top.top.location.href='http://xx.com/index.html';
```

When I click the link open new window, redirect.php openin in new window and redirecting http://xx.com/index.html. Problem is here: in this page a javascript code forcing to close this new window and redirect main window to http://xx.com/index.html.

javascript code http://xx.com/index.html has:

```
try{
        if(opener) {
            opener.location.href=this.location.href;
            top.close();
        }
    }
```

How can I prevent main page from closing by child window?

[this is live example](http://bstate.english.qgroupus.com/Browse/default.aspx)

Comment: Put some more effort into your question. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Ok, I gave more details.

Answer (score 0):

In your code (http://xx.com/index.html)

```
try{
    if(opener) {
        opener.location.href=this.location.href; // Line-1
        top.close(); // Line-2
    }
}
```

**1.** Line-1 is redirecting the opener (parent/main window) not closing it, the **opener** property returns a reference to the window that opened the window, so if you remove Line-1 it won't be redirected anymore.

**2.** Line-2 is closing the current (**the child window itself referred by top**) window, so if you remove this line it won't be closed anymore.

Just remove whole try block, your problem will be solved and I'm confused why didn't you remove those lines by yourself as because you knew those codes are responsible for the problem you described in your question.

Comment: I think, I could not explain my problem properly. I can not change (http://xx.com/index.html) page. I am linking this site from mine, and I want (http://xx.com/index.html) not to close mine.